# Android Dev - Why buffer errors in console when running app?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-layout, android-studio

**Hey all, thanks for taking the time to help answer my question!**

I'm testing a very simple splash screen, which works perfectly fine - in fact, the app runs just fine within the emulator - however I noticed in the console there are a couple of red lines, and am curious why they are there, since the app is so simple:

(I created a new project, added a new activity and changed it to be the launcher etc, and in the onCreate I simply show a layout and have a thread run which sleeps for 5 seconds prior to launching my main activity - which I havent changed at all).

The first red line appears [after] my splash, upon loading my main:

```
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f20f04022a0
```

The second red line appears when I click the [back] button in the emulator, to exit the app:

```
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f20f50c2e70
```

Anybody know what this might be caused by? **or if it will even affect my app at all?**

Thanks

Comment: **PS..** Is this caused by the app package itself, **OR** by the graphics of the emulator and my computer?